# ActionListener principles

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, actionlistener

I am trying to find basic principles of adding action to `JButton` or other components. Here is what I am doing and what am I getting.

I have created a class named : Ali which has a main method in it, inside the main method Instantiate another method called: `MainFrame` and Whatever components I have I put in here.

I have created a simple button here, registered that with `ActionListener` interface, and I wrote an `actionPerformed()` method for that. Very simple and easy. But, somehow this program giving an error to me.
Here is the simplified codes and and errors.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Ali{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new MainFrameAli2("MainFrameAli2");
                frame.setSize(400,600);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the `MainFrameAli2` class

```
public class MainFrameAli2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public MainFrameAli2(String title){
        super(title);

        // set layout manager
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // create swing component
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        JButton button = new JButton("click");

        // add swing components to content pane
        Container c  = getContentPane();
        c.add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // add behavior
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Clicked");
            }
            });
    }
}
```

Now the problem is code is not running, here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The public type MainFrameAli2 must be defined in its own file
    The type MainFrameAli2 must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
```

And, if I write the code like below, everything is working OK.

```
        // add behavior
    button.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
    System.out.println("hooyt");
}
}
```

Why it is not working in the first case and working in second case?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: 1) `Unresolved compilation problems`  Don't try to run code before it compiles cleanly! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so, why it is not working in the first case and working in second case.?

Like the compiler message says, in the first example you didn't implement the ActionListener interface in your MainFrameAli2 class.

You created an anonymous inner class which implements the ActionListener interface. This is not the same thing as having your class implement the interface.

In the second example your class does implement the ActionListener.

If the first example you could have done:

```
//public class MainFrameAli2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
public class MainFrameAli2 extends JFrame {
```

Comment: By the way you said "You created an anonymous inner class which implements the ActionListener interface". by "inner class " ,do you mean (new ActionListener ()) ? and by that did you actually mean an interface? isnt ActionListener an interface? Thanks

Comment: @user1971804, `do you mean..` - yes, along with the code between the `{...});`. ` did you actually mean an interface?` - no, I meant class. In this case you create an annonymous inner class that happens to implement the ActionListener interface, but you can also use an inner class to extend any other class simply by overriding a method of that class.